# Chrome showing cached JSON after navigating to new page and hitting back button using Ruby on Rails as backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, browser-history

**Problem**:

After leaving a page that uses pushState and popState to handle back and forward navigation when retrieving HTML and JSON from the same base URL, returning to the page using the back button shows the cached JSON instead of the HTML.

**Description**:

1. Using Ajax calls to page through search results in our application using the same URL as page URL, but with format=json.
2. On each page a `window.history.pushState(state,null,url)` is called.
3. popState is used internally when the back and forward buttons are used within this page.
4. Results have links that load other pages. (This application is not a SPA)
5. After clicking on one of these links and then clicking the 'Back' button, Chrome shows the JSON stored in the state and not the previous page with a console error:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json

Firefox and Safari correctly reload the page and since I am updating the URL in the pushState call they correctly reload the page to the state I wish (i.e. the url has the correct page identification and, therefore, reloads the correct page of the search results).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the answer was turning off caching of the JSON or convincing Chrome that the cached JSON wasn't what was wanted. Based on another question's answer, I added `response.headers['Vary'] = 'Accept'` in the rails controller when returning JSON.

So, in context:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do 
    render :template => xxx
  end
  format.json do
    response.headers['Vary'] = 'Accept'
    render :json => {...}
  end
end
```

Questions that helped me:

- [JSON breaking back button in Chrome, Reload Button in IE (Showing as naked data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715852/json-breaking-back-button-in-chrome-reload-button-in-ie-showing-as-naked-data?rq=1)
- Another I can't seem to relocate that suggested the 'Vary' header

Comment: I don't use Rails, but I had a similar problem and this helped. Thanks! I found this explanation of the `Vary` header helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975924/1079869

Comment: Indeed: setting "Vary:Accept" tells Chrome that there is a possibility that this url returns various "Content-Type"'s. So this setting on server side fixes it.

Comment: In PHP, I added `header('Vary: Accept');` right before I return all JSON, and boom! it worked. Thanks.